# Angular search : filter pipe show only data from current showed page

Tags: html, angular, search, filter, pagination

I'm getting data from node sever and display it with angular in component, I'm using paginate of angular and want to make a search area tat filter what user want, the filter search only in the current page and not in the whole data !

here is the html code :

```
  <div class="col-4 offset-2 select form-group">
      <input class="form-control" type="text" name="search" [(ngModel)]="searchText"  placeholder="&#61442;  chercher un sondage "> 
    </div>

  <div class="widget-body">
    <div class="ui link cards row divCards">
      <div class="card" *ngFor="let sondage of filteredSurveys | paginate:{  itemsPerPage:10, currentPage: p } | filter:searchText;  let i=index" [attr.data-tooltip]="sondage.status | uppercase"  > 

        <div class="content">
          <div class="header"> {{sondage.title}} 
          <div class="meta right floated">
            <i *ngIf="sondage.status=='waiting'" class="hourglass half icon" style=" color: rgb(196, 61, 61);"></i>
            <i *ngIf="sondage.status=='live'" class="play icon pulsate" style="color: rgb(7, 91, 216);"></i>
            <i *ngIf="sondage.status=='paused'" class="pause icon  pulsate"  style="color: orange;"></i>
            <i *ngIf="sondage.status=='done'" class="check circle icon noAfter"  style="color: green;"></i>
            <i *ngIf="sondage.status=='closed'" class="window close icon" style="color: rgb(4, 41, 27);"></i>
          </div></div>
            <div class="image ">
            <img  src="https://via.placeholder.com/{{ 150+(10*i) }}" alt="">  
            </div>
          <div class="meta divIcon">
            <a [routerLink]="['/sondage/single/' + sondage._id]"><i class="la la-pie-chart edit settings"></i></a>
            <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" [attr.data-target]="'#modal-link' + i"><i
                class="la la-link edit settings"></i></a>

                <a data-toggle="tooltip"  title="Metre en direct" *ngIf="sondage.status != 'live'"
                (click)=startSurvey(sondage._id)><i id="playPause" class="la la-play delete settings" ></i></a>

              <a data-toggle="tooltip" title="Pauser sondage" *ngIf="sondage.status == 'live'"
                (click)="pauseSurvey(sondage._id)"><i id="playPause" class="la la-pause delete settings"></i></a>
              <a data-toggle="tooltip" title="Supprimer sondage" href="#" data-toggle="modal"
                [attr.data-target]="'#supp' + i"><i class="la la-trash delete settings"></i></a>
          </div>

          <div class="description">
             {{sondage.object}}
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="extra content">
          <span class="right floated">
            <i class="calendar times icon"></i>
            {{sondage.endDate |date }}
          </span>
          <span>
            <i class="calendar plus icon"></i>
            {{sondage.startDate |date }}
          </span>
        </div>
        <div [attr.id]="'modal-link' + i" class="modal fade">
          <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered">
            <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title">Sondage : {{ sondage.title }}</h4>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">
                  <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
                  <span class="sr-only">close</span>
                </button>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body">
                <h4 class="text-gradient-02">Copier le lien:</h4>
                <div class="form-group row d-flex align-items-center">
                  <div class="col">
                    <div class="input-group">

                      <input type="text" class="form-control"
                        [attr.value]="'https://www.baladiaty.tn/#/sondages/single/' + sondage._id">
                      <span class="input-group-addon addon-primary rounded-right">
                        <i class="la la-link"></i>
                      </span>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <p-card>
                  <p-header>
                      Header content here
                  </p-header>
                  Body Content
                  <p-footer>
                      Footer content here
                  </p-footer>
              </p-card>   </div>
              <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Ok</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div [attr.id]="'supp' + i" class="modal fade">
          <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered">
            <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title">Supprimer un sondage</h4>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">
                  <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
                  <span class="sr-only">close</span>
                </button>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body">
                <h4 class="text-gradient-02">Êtes-vous sûr de vouloir supprimer ce sondage?</h4>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-footer">
                <button class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Annuler</button>
                <button type="submit" (click)="deleteSurvey(sondage._id)" class="btn btn-primary"
                  data-dismiss="modal">Confirmer</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
      <div class="col-12">

        <pagination-controls  style="text-align: center;" class="my-pagination" (pageChange)="p = $event"></pagination-controls>

      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
```

---

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-sondages-all',
  templateUrl: './sondages-all.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./sondages-all.component.css']
})

export class SondagesAllComponent implements OnInit {
  surveys: any[] = [];
  filteredSurveys: any[];
  p: number = 1;
  searchText;
  cols: any[];
  loading: boolean = true;

  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getSurveys();
  }

  getSurveys() {

    this.http.get("/api/surveys").subscribe((surveys: any[]) => {
      this.surveys = surveys;
      this.filteredSurveys = this.surveys;
      this.loading = false;
    })
  }

}
```

I am missing some thing here so that I can get filter result from all data ( filteredSurveys) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to inverse filters order as follows:

```
   *ngFor="let sondage of filteredSurveys | filter:searchText;  | paginate:{  itemsPerPage:10, currentPage: p }
```

Answer (score 0):

Angular `Pipes` are `pure` by default. That means, the `pipe` logic will be triggered only when your "piped" object changes. I can't see anywhere you change your `filteredSurveys`, only in `ngOnInit` when you make `Http` call. What you should do, if you want to achieve pagination, you have to do one of two things. You can change your `Pipe` to `unpure` by setting it property in decorator `pure=false`. Or you can remove pipe and in your array `filteredSurveys`have already filtered values. And then programatically change `p` and update this array inside of component.